# Queries to fetch items based on top Ranks

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table which rank the items which i have.

I need a queries which will pick up only the top 2 ranks for a given item, the rank may not be in sequential order.

I need to fetch the item with least two ranks, there will same rank for two items as well.

Here is the snap shot of my table.

```
Item Id Supp Id Rank
1   2   2
1   1   7
1   7   5
1   9   11
2   67  4
2   9   14
2   10  14
2   34  4
2   25  3
2   60  3
2   79  5
```

my requirement is if I enter 2 i should get the result as below

```
Item Id Supp_id Rank
2   25  3
2   60  3
2   67  4
2   34  4
```

I am using oracle 10g version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of the approaches it can be done as follows. Here we are using [dense_rank() over()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions045.htm#i1064409) analytic function to assign a rank for a row in a ordered by `rank` group of rows .

```
select t.item_id
     , t.supp_id
     , t.rank
  from (select item_id
             , supp_id
             , rank
             , dense_rank() over(partition by item_id 
                                     order by rank) as rn
          from t1
          where item_id = 2 
         ) t
where t.rn <= 2
```

Result:

```
   ITEM_ID    SUPP_ID       RANK
---------- ---------- ----------
         2         25          3 
         2         60          3 
         2         67          4 
         2         34          4
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f36cf/1)